# WWW version of website is showing at the end of the URL [domain]index.php?p=index.html

Tags: .htaccess, no-www

We have a website set up using the non WWW version of the website. At the moment when you access the WWW version of the domain it seems to redirect to `www.ourdomain.com/index.php?p=index.html`.

We are seeing the homepage template but with errors. (e.g. Images aren't loading). Does anyone know what would be the best way to fix what is happening or the potential causes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your browsers web inspector tools to see why assets like images aren't loading. Quite possibly it's because they are trying to load from the wrong domain.

If you didn't set the site URL in `/craft/config/general.php` then the URL set in your admin site settings will be used, so check that is correct first.

[image]

Removing the index.php?… part is covered in detail in [Craft's Documentation](https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php) so not worth repeating here.